# Filemaker Version Control?

Tags: version-control, github, filemaker

Is there any existing Filemaker version control solutions available?  I'm working on two diverging FM projects that share scripts and custom functions.  Updating both FM files is becoming a nightmare.  Does anybody know of any solutions or have any advice for me?

I heard that people use github to manage text versions of Filemaker custom functions.  I was wondering how people typically use these text base repositories with their FM files.  Is there a way to import these text functions? Or if you have to manually manage these functions though the FM function interface and the use of text files are just a way to share them.  Just being able to push custom function changes both FM files would greatly reduce my problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, it is possible to import Scripts into a FileMaker solution. There is no way to share selected attributes of one FileMaker solution, with another. Deleting scripts in a database to import new scripts will lose assoication with the object set-up to trigger the script.

Replication is possible with a FileMaker solution, however this will obviously generate identical solutions.

Opening two or more same/similar solutions in the same FileMaker Pro client can cause confusion and caution should be taken.

FileMaker is not as modular as OOP applications. Something I have long requested for re-usability, but unfortunately the only method to consistently share features is to manually implement them into a file. We have tried imports of data, custom functions, etc, but found double entry the most reliable method following a change management procedure.

Depending on your application, it maybe possible to implement the data separation model, however I would need to understand the scenario to advise this.

Answer (score 1):

[MyFMButler Clip Manager](http://www.myfmbutler.com/en/products/clip-manager-for-mac/6) allows you to store a library re-usable "snippets", be they fields, script blocks, etc. While importing scripts will break associations, if you use FileMaker Advanced, you can copy and paste script steps into existing scripts, which will preserve them. So there's no easy way to push out changes, but with some effort it's possible to keep a master library to manually update dependent files from.

Answer (score 1):

[FMVersion](https://fmversion.com/features) tracks changes between versions of a FileMaker application. You just upload a [DDR](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/docs/18/en/ddrxml/) or the [XML introduced in FileMaker 18](https://fmhelp.filemaker.com/help/18/fmp/en/#page/FMP_Help%2Fsave-a-copy-as-xml.html) and it shows you the differences between the versions.
So it will let you know what changes have been made to your FileMaker elements so you know what to rebuild in the other file.